# Javascript, how to check if handler is attached

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I run `dispatchEvent`, on an element that has no handlers attached, nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title is required</title>
<script>
  function submitHandlers() {
    var target = document.getElementById('myForm');

    var event = new Event('submit');
    var result = target.dispatchEvent(event);

    // nothing happens because no handler is attached to target submit event
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="this is a test">
    <input type="button" value="JS Submit Handlers" onclick="submitHandlers()" >
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I determine that no handler is attached an then decide to manually run the `document.getElementById('myForm').submit();` ?

I need a Vanilla Js answer...

In pseudo Javascript it would be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title is required</title>
<script>
  function submitHandlers() {
    var target = document.getElementById('myForm');

    if(target.hasEventListener('submit')) {
      var event = new Event('submit');
      var result = target.dispatchEvent(event);
    }   
    else {
      target.submit();
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="this is a test">
    <input type="button" value="JS Submit Handlers" onclick="submitHandlers()" >
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I think that this is a Chrome issue, Firefox behavior is different: when you call `dispatchEvent` if no custom handler is defined, it fires the native "html" submit event (the same as `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()`)

Comment: Are you the one attaching the might-be-absent submit handler, or is something else doing that?

Comment: unfortunately I have no control over the might-be-absent submit handler

Comment: Would it be acceptable in your use-case to just add a submit handler,`stopPropagation()` and always handle the form submission yourself?

Comment: Why not just do `target.submit();` , IMHO if you are not responsible for attaching submit events then all you can do is execute it and you are done. I would just let it blow up and ask who is responsible for attaching the event to deal with the error. Worst case if no other way, wrap a `try/catch` around the execution and log the error instead and pass on the error to whom is responsible for the event to be attached.

Comment: With `target.submit();` handlers eventually attached won't get executed

Comment: From the MDN Docs: The [dispatchEvent() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) throws UNSPECIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_ERR if the event's type was not specified by initializing the event before the method was called, or if the event's type is null or an empty string.